# Django Scheduled Deletion

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to delete a model after a specified amount of time since creation? Basically, I want to retain a model for only a twenty four hours such that it expires after this duration has been reached.

Comment: Bear in mind that I do not want to filter through time fields. I want to actually delete.

Comment: Does it have to be deleted immediately or would it be okay to leave it alive but marked for deletion and just have a script go through and clean things up N times a day?

Comment: I would like to delete immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) task to delete the model.  Use a [`post-save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal handler to trigger the celery deletion task (with a delay of 24 hours) for the model (when `created` is `True`).

---

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def delete_model(model_pk):
    try:
        MyModel.objects.get(pk=model_pk).delete()
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

---

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def model_expiration(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
         delete_model.apply_async(
            args=(instance.pk,), 
            eta=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24)
         )
```

Comment: I'm not familar with celery or how to integrate it with a model. Could you include a code sample?

Comment: [`celery`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a very mature and well documented tool that you'll appreciate learning.